# ODE Joint, Static friction

Tags: gazebo, friction

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear All,

In my model I have a horizontally placed slider joint, this gradually moves because apperently numerical error cause it to not be exactly horizontal (angular noise with a magnitude of ~ |1e-4|). Because there is no friction, it drifts towards it's limit.
*(The bounce at the limit is somewhat unrealistic too, but im not interested in that atm (it adds energy, despite the settings)).*

Not an issue since the real robot will also be imperfect. However static friction in the slider joint should stop it from moving, however this settings seems to have no effect!
I've noticed in ODE documentation that regular joints (and Gazebo api), that regular joints don't have such atributes (static friction), only the contact joint has this. I'd be great if static friction would work, any way this is possible. Here is the joint code:

```
<joint name="joint_2" type="prismatic">
    <parent>link_1r</parent>
    <child>puppet</child>
    <pose>0.0000 0.0000 0.00000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 </pose>
    <axis>
        <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        <limit>
            <lower>-0.1</lower>
            <upper>0.1</upper>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
            <damping>0.01</damping>
            <friction>0.1</friction>
        </dynamics>
    </axis>
</joint>
```

I can create some actual contact friction, by recreating bearings and such, but that seems overly complication and prone to error.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/183/ode-joint,-static-friction/) by [Erik Stoltenborg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/77/erik-stoltenborg/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You are correct that we do not currently support joint friction with ODE. I've added this to the gazebo issue tracker as [issue #381](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/381).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0